# Why is $\{f\,|\,f\colon A\to\mathbb N\}$ not uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $S=\{\,f\,|\,f\colon A\to\mathbb N\}$, where $A=\{1,2\}$.

I thought cardinality of $S$ is $2^{|\mathbb N|}=\aleph_0$. But my friend told that my answer was wrong.

Please help me where is I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you think the cardinality of $S$ would be $2^{|\mathbb N|}$?

Comment: Because for any function to defined every point has 2 choices so there are 2^|N|.I thought

Comment: Note that the set $S = \{ f$ a function$ : f:\mathbb{N}\to\{1,2\}\}$ is uncountable. To see why, think about $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ for $f\in S$.

Comment: You could just list down all the functions in your set and see what the answer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of the set of functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$.

In particular in your case the size of $S$ is $|\mathbb{N}|^2$ (not $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$) which is the size of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ (hence countable).